# How to fix the MonadFail (Either String) Error using explicit pattern matching

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I was trying to adapt an old Haskell project which is now not compatible with latest GHC (`MonadFail` is now default).

```
applyCosPass :: CosCtx a => (a -> QueryExpr -> Either String QueryExpr)
                  -> a -> QueryExpr -> Either String QueryExpr
applyCosPass p c (UnionAll q1 q2) =
  UnionAll <$> applyCosPass p c q1 <*> applyCosPass p c q2
applyCosPass p c (Select sl f w g d) =
     do (Select sl' f' w' g' d') <- p c (Select sl f w g d)
     nsl <- (checkListErr $ map convSI sl')
     nf <- newFr f'
     nw <- newWh w'
     return $ Select nsl nf nw g' d'
  where ...
```

It returns the error as follows:

```
• Could not deduce (MonadFail (Either String))
        arising from a do statement
        with the failable pattern ‘(Select sl' f' w' g' d')’
      from the context: CosCtx a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   applyCosPass :: forall a.
                                   CosCtx a =>
                                   (a -> QueryExpr -> Either String QueryExpr)
                                   -> a -> QueryExpr -> Either String QueryExpr
        at src/CosetteParser.lhs:(648,3)-(649,63)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (Select sl' f' w' g' d') <- (case slstmt of
                                       Left s -> error s
                                       Right e -> Right e)
```

According to option 2 "[Adapting New Code](https://gitlab.haskell.org/haskell/prime/-/wikis/libraries/proposals/monad-fail#adapting-old-code)" from the Haskell Wiki, the code was revised to an explicit pattern matching, but the error remains. What is possibly missing here?

```
applyCosPass p c (Select sl f w g d) =
     do {(Select sl' f' w' g' d') <- (case slstmt of
                                Left s -> error s
                                Right e -> Right e);
     nsl <- (checkListErr $ map convSI sl');
     nf <- newFr f';
     nw <- newWh w';
     return $ Select nsl nf nw g' d'}
  where slstmt = p c (Select sl f w g d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean explicit pattern matching like this:

```
applyCosPass :: CosCtx a => (a -> QueryExpr -> Either String QueryExpr)
                 -> a -> QueryExpr -> Either String QueryExpr
applyCosPass p c (UnionAll q1 q2) =
  UnionAll <$> applyCosPass p c q1 <*> applyCosPass p c q2
applyCosPass p c (Select sl f w g d) = do
     slstmt <- p c (Select sl f w g d)
     case slstmt of
       Select sl' f' w' g' d' -> do
         nsl <- (checkListErr $ map convSI sl')
         nf <- newFr f'
         nw <- newWh w'
         return $ Select nsl nf nw g' d'
       ... other cases -> error "Pattern match failed" -- Boooo
  where ...
```

No pattern match should remain on the left side of a `<-` arrow in the do notation.

Note that you should check whether `Select ...` is really the only case that is possible here, otherwise you should probably handle the other cases.

Comment: Manually writing what GHC used to automatically write seems like a good default alternative to `error` -- e.g. something like `_ -> Left "Non-exhaustive pattern in applyCosPass"`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't think the `Monad` instance of `Either` has ever implemented `fail` in that way (because the `Left` constructor does not always hold a string; that would require flexible and overlapping instances), but that is a good suggestion in this case.

Comment: Hm. That is my memory of how it used to work in the ancient past. More generically, for `Either e` it would use [`strMsg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:strMsg) to inject its compiler-generated `String` into your custom error type. In fact, as I recall, one of the reasons floated for changing away from this was that this violates referential transparency, because inlining an `Either`-based `do` block would change the error message! (If it actually used `error`, this would be referentially transparent, as `error`s are indistinguishable.)

Comment: @DanielWagner that sounds plausible, but I cannot find any evidence of that in old base packages. In base-4.6.0.1 the monad instance of `Either` did not override fail and the default implementation was `fail s = error s`.

Comment: @Noughtmare There was some discussion on the Monad instance of `Either` implementing `fail` as `Left`. [link](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/12160). Well, the final conclusion was leave it to users. (You might already know it).

Comment: @Noughtmare Thank you, it works. Well, I have a follow up question which is "How can I pass on the error message?" `p c (Select sl f w g d)` is of the type `Either String QueryExpr`.

Comment: @EmmaLiu if that `p c (Select sl f w g d)` returns a `Left ...` then the monadic bind (which is what do notation uses under the hood) will automatically stop executing the rest and immediately return that `Left ...` value. That is how the monad instance of either works.

Comment: @Noughtmare Get what you mean. Thank you.